# Differentiate between 2 and 02 in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, command-line-arguments, wget

I have a bash script that takes the date, month and year as separate arguments. Using that, a url is constructed which then uses `wget` to fetch content and store it in an html file (say t.html). Now, the user may enter a 2 digit month/date (as in 02 instead of just 2 and vice-versa). How do I distinguish between the above two formats and correct for this from within the script?

The url works as follows:
**Date**: a 2 digit input is needed. So a 7 must be supplied as 07 for the url to be constructed properly. Here I am looking for a check that would append a zero to the date in case it is less than 10 and does not already have a zero in front. So, 7 should become 07 for the date field before the url is constructed.
**Month**: a 2 digit input is needed, but here the url automatically appends the 0 in case month < 10. So, if the user enters 2, then the url forms 02, but if the user enters 02, the url forms 002. Here, the 0 may need to be appended or removed.

P.S: I know this method followed by the url s*c&s, but I just need to work with it.

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're asking for. If you're only looking to strip one leading zero, then this will do:

```
month=${month#0}
```

This will turn `02` into `2`, and `12` remains `12`.

If you need to remove more than one zero (above `002` will turn into `02`), you'll need to do something different, like using regular expressions

```
while [ -z "${month##0*}" ]; do month=${month#0}; done
```

or use regular expressions, like with `sed`

```
month=$(sed -e 's/^0*//'<<<"$month")
```

HTH

**EDIT**
As per your edit; as has already been suggested, use `printf`

```
month=$(printf %02d "$month")
```

this will turn `2` into `02`, `12` remains as is, as does `123`. If you want to force a two digit number or you don't have `printf` (which is a shell built-in in bash, and usually available otherwise too, so chances are pretty low), `sed` can help again

```
month=$(sed -e 's/.*\(..\)$/\1/'<<<"00$month")
```

which will prepend two zeros (`002`) and keep the last two characters (`02`), turning the empty string into `00` as well. This will turn `a` into `0a` too though. Come to think of it, you don't need `sed` for this

```
month="00$month"
month="${month:0-2}"
```

(The `0-` is required to disambiguate from default value expansion)

Comment: @roe: Thanks for the response! I have edited my question as above.

Comment: You can also do `month="${month: -2}"` or `month="${month:(-2)}"`

Comment: `printf` is POSIX since years, so there's very good chance of having it everywhere:)

Comment: @Dennis; interesting, never occurred to me to use space. I know you can use arbitrary arithmetic including brackets (`2*-1` will work too), but I personally think less is more. I'll start using the space instead of 0 though, makes it easier on the eyes.

Comment: @pooh; yeah, as I said it's not very likely, but I suppose it's always good learn different things. Different expansion options in bash are often overlooked, which is a shame, as they're really quite powerful. Incidentally, do you know if `printf` is available in busybox?

Comment: @roe: Yes, there is `printf` in busybox. I admire bash extensions, but unfortunately cannot use them because i'm into portable shell programming, so sometimes they get quite hairy, the workarounds... Like associative arrays i've mentioned somewhere yesterday:)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `printf`.

For example `$(printf "%02d" $day)` to add the leading zero in case.
And `$(printf "%1d" $month)` to strip the zero in case.

Answer (score 2):

To strip all leading zeros, regardless of the number and regardless of the number of final digits (it fixes "010" for example):

```
shopt -s extglob
month=009
month=${month##+(0)}
echo "$month"
```

Demo:

```
$ for a in 2 02 002 0002 20 020 00200; do echo ${a##+(0)}; done
2
2
2
2
20
20
200
```

To fix any date:

```
shopt -s extglob
fixdigits () {
    if (( ${#1} > 2 || ${#1} < 1 ))
    then
        echo "Invalid number of digits"
        return 1
    fi
    printf '%.2d\n' 0${1##+(0)}
}
```

Demo:

```
$ for a in 2 02 002 0002 20 020 00200; do fixdigits $a; done
02
02
Invalid number of digits
Invalid number of digits
02
Invalid number of digits
Invalid number of digits
```

Alternatively:

```
shopt -s extglob
fixdigits () {
    digits=${1##+(0)}
    if (( ${#digits} > 2 || ${#digits} < 1 ))
    then
        echo "Invalid number of digits"
        return 1
    fi
    printf '%.2s\n' 0$digits
}
```

Demo:

```
$ for a in 2 02 002 0002 20 020 00200; do fixdigits $a; done
02
02
02
02
02
02
Invalid number of digits
```

Comment: oh nice, extglob, I always forget about that one. +1

Comment: That is very neat, but my problem is a simpler one, that got answered with roe's solution. Thanks much for replying!